# Release problem with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, memory-leaks, uiimage

I am trying to convert a `UIView` to a `UIImage` and place it in a `UITableViewCell` using the following code (simplified):

```
MyUIView *myView = [[[MyUIView alloc] init] autorelease];
.
.
.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The program crashes with **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** in `MyUIView`.

If I remove the autorelease from the first statement the program doesn't crash but then I get a memory leak.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyUIView *myView = [[[MyUIView alloc] init] autorelease];
.
.
.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * myNewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

cell.imageView.image = myNewImage;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this doesn't help, I still get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The error is raised in a @synthesize statement of the first private property in MyUIView, which indicates that the view is released prematurely.